# Find n rows with highest value for column periodically

Tags: python, mysql, database

I am creating a leaderboard, and want the results to be updated in "near" real-time on client side.

Here is what my table look like :

```
╔════╦═════════════════╦════════════╦════════╗
║ id ║ author          ║topic       ║  count ║
╠════╬═════════════════╬════════════╬════════╣
║  1 ║ jazzgarza       ║ nowplaying ║      1 ║
║  2 ║ DJBure          ║ nowplaying ║     16 ║
║  3 ║ GRC__romoly     ║ nowplaying ║      5 ║
║  4 ║ MarineBerteloot ║ wtf        ║      1 ║
║  5 ║ Nick_Lukitsh    ║ nowplaying ║      1 ║
║  6 ║ Mugen__         ║ nowplaying ║      2 ║
║  7 ║ MaxChebotarev   ║ nowplaying ║      6 ║
║  8 ║ radeonvelcro    ║ nowplaying ║      9 ║
║  9 ║ SF1033          ║ nowplaying ║    102 ║
╚════╩═════════════════╩════════════╩════════╝
```

I basically want to be able to retrieve the n rows with the highest count for a given topic.
I want to do that for each topic, and **n** may change depending on the topic.

currently, I have a simple dumb SQL query that I run periodically (every second or so and for each topic).

```
SELECT * FROM member WHERE member.topic = 'wtf' ORDER BY member.count DESC
```

But my table is growing really quickly (something like 7 more users per second) and my solution is definitely not scaling correctly. 
 I tried adding an index, but this is probably only a quick fix that won't do the trick forever. **n** could go somewhere between 3 and 50, and I want to be able to track several hundreds topic simultaneously.

So my question is, what would be a more clever way to do this?

I am open to pretty much anything. My solution doesn't have to be pure SQL, as long as it can be retrieved afterwards client side.

Comment: Well, first I would add a limit n to the end of your query

Comment: I can't see where n figures in your explanation? Given the dataset aabove, what would the complete result set look like when n=2?

Comment: because it isn't . My n is afterwards in my python code, where I strip the results down to n rows. I didn't know about the LIMIT keyword, which is likely to help a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query fetch the first 2 result from topic `wtf` and first 3 result from topic `nowplaying`:

```
(SELECT * FROM member WHERE topic = 'wtf' ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 3) UNION (SELECT * FROM member WHERE topic = 'nowplaying' ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 3)
```

This is the [fiddle link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c5da82/6).

Comment: That sounds awesome. With the index, I can imagine this working for a long time without problem. I can parse the results in my python code afterwards. I'll give a shot to it

Answer (score 1):

It's very hard to give a one-size-fits-all answer.

Adding and index and a `limit` instruction to your SQL query might be enough.

If you need something that scales much more, maybe the solution would be to have different versions of the DB, on different servers, one per topic.

The next step, if your database has to deal with billions of records, is to use so sort of NoSQL system, but I suppose you won't need to go that far.

Comment: thx for the answer. I actually thought about creating several dbs, one per topic. But I am heavily limited in terms of SQL connections and have to find a way to g through that. I'll look at it too :)

Answer (score 1):

Why wouldn't you add a memory-based storage such as a map indexed by topic which gives the list of your `n` top players (ordered by count) ?

If the memory can't contains all the data you can also implement a cache solution.

This map would be filled on the startup of the application and then updated asynchronously (since you only needs near real-time) by a thread of your application.

This way, the access to it will be in constant time from a client point of view, and the refresh won't be done for each hit toward your application, but at a specified rate.

Hope it helps,

Best regards